# Query a table with TOM - Analysis Services C#

Tags: c#, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, tom

I have a project of Net Core which it create database, tables and measures in a Tabular model. I would like to query some tables like we would do in SQL, for example, *"select * from myTable"*. I've seen Microsoft documentation but I can't find an example that explains how to query a table of my tabular model. How can I do it? Could you give me an example?

I would like to query the cube and get a array like:

| TableA.Column1 | TableA.Column2 | TableB.Column1 | TableC.MeasureA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Marketing | Rosario | $999 |
| 2 | Finance | Córdoba | $456 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The DAX equivalent for SELECT is [EVALUATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/evaluate-statement-dax), the equivalent for

```
select * from myTable
```

is

```
evaluate 'myTable'
```

Comment: Hi thanks. But, I would like to see an example in C# code. How to query multiple tables dynamically from C#

Comment: It's normal ADO.NET programming.  So create an AdomdCommand, and call .ExecuteReader().  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/adomd/multidimensional-models-adomd-net-client/retrieving-data-using-the-adomddatareader?view=asallproducts-allversions